# Use a bootstrap custom variables file with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, webpacker

I am trying to apply my custom bootstrap variables to a rails app using webpacker and bootstrap.

`rails new testapp --webpack
cd testapp
yarn add bootstrap`

In my app/javascript/packs folder I have

- _custom.scss
- application.js
- vendor.scss

application.js:

`import 'bootstrap'`

vendor.scss:

`@import 'custom';
@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap';`

custom.scss

`$brand-success:         red !default;`

It says on the bootstrap guide that you need to configure some css loaders in your webpack config however it says that webpacker comes with those by default.

Bootstrap is working fine however it won't compile with my custom variables. Has somebody got an example of this working with webpacker?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue and haven't been able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple really, you aren't compile bootstrap because you are using the already compiled dist css of it.

Change to this and it will be compiled for the pack

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

Comment: This doesn't work, at least for the bootstrap version 3.3.x as the scss folder doesn't exists.

Comment: I read that bootstrap switched from less to sass since version 4, so this answer is fine for version 4, but another answer should be posted for bootstrap 3 since the questioner didn't specified the bootstrap version.

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap 3

Bootstrap 3 uses the less preprocessor so you have to use the [less-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader).

Today SASS is much more used so it is very likely that you're already using the [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) in your Webpack config.

What works well for me was to use the SASS version of Bootstrap 3.

1. First step is to remove the bootstrap package :

```
yarn remove bootstrap
```

2. Now install the bootstrap-sass package (it ships the bootstrap version 3.3.6) :

```
yarn add bootstrap-sass
```

3. From your SASS/SCSS file import it :

```
// Include your variables here, before the import.

@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap";
```

#### If it fails to load glyphicons

I had the issue that loading glyphicons failed. Fortunately bootstrap uses the `$icon-font-path` variable to defines from where to load it.

I had to override it like so :

```
$icon-font-path: "../../fonts/bootstrap/" !default;
```

Then all loads fine.